# Vimeo video in html5 video tag firefox

Tags: html, video, vimeo

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/fzzgjem4/2/

I'm using the video tage to show a vimeo video.

I would normally use the iframe from vimeo but I want it full width and without the vimeo controls.

I'm getting the src from 'Use your own player section' in vimeo.

The video will come from a CMS so I just want to be able to add the id for the video.

The jsfiddle does not work in Firefox.

Is this becasue it's the wrong format?

Is it possible to use the video tag to show vimeo videos

```
    <video src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4" autoplay muted></video>
```

Comment: Do you mean it only works in Firefox? You aren't clear as to what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry, it does not work in firefox. It works in Safari, Chrome and Opera. I haven't tested IE yet

Comment: Weird, your fiddle works fine for me in Firefox 35.0.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: OK thats interesting I need to investigate more than

Comment: MP4 should work fine in newer Firefox versions, what version are you testing it on?

Comment: The url in that src actually redirects to a url with aksessionid= and token= in the url. This makes me wonder if this may actually expire the session and break at some point. Also, specifying only one video source will make it only work in browsers that happen to have whatever mp4 codec they use. What api did you use to get this video url, and is it part of the "official" api?